# Get Secured cookie from curl after authentication (c++)

Tags: c++, authentication, curl, cookies, oauth-2.0

How to get secured cookie from curl after authentication?

curl_easy_getinfo(curl_handler, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST, &cookies); 
fetched only one cookie, the other secured cookie wasnt fetched.

Same with
 curl_easy_setopt(curl_handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");

However in java we could use cookie manager for login and after all the operations if we iterated the cookie manager there were two of them "Cookie" and "_WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID".

In curl  i am not able to fetch "_WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID" .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, curl should get the same set of cookies that any other HTTP client gets.

Unfortunately, that is a *should* as servers sometimes act different depending on which client it thinks it speaks to and thus it may respond differently. Also, since you're comparing with another client it is possible that the java version you see did some more HTTP requests that made it get the second cookie your curl request doesn't.

To minimize the risk for all this, make sure the requests are as similar as possible so that the server cannot spot a difference between your clients and then it should repond identically and you will get the same set of cookies in both cases.

When the curl based client gets both cookies, you can extract them fine with CURLINFO_COOKIELIST just as you want.